# detect plain text or html

Tags: php, email, text-processing

In my application I am processing mail texts using PHP. For some mail clients such as sina.com is sending bad headers. For example, they are sending HTML mail but sending the header Content-Type as text/plain.

Now, for these mails, my application is considering the HTML as text. In PHP how can I detect if a text contain html text or not?

Comment: use [strip_tag](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) and send it as text  or u can compare the string before and after this function

Comment: From a philosophical point of view, your application **should not** attempt to correct the *flagrantly incorrect* MIME header.  If the mail is marked `text/plain`, then you should treat it as `text/plain`, *not* `text/html`.  Content type sniffing is one of the many things that made IE such a security nightmare, and you don't want to go down that same road.

Comment: Not an exact solution, but you could strip_tags to make all the content text only. Another option would be to use a regexp for any html tags, but I am not skilled enough with regexps to write that. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use `strip_tags()` and compare filtered mail-body with original one to see are there any differences but don't forget, in plain-text you may have HTML tags as normal text and I think that `strip_tags()` will remove these tags too.

Comment: Sorry @Wh1T3h4Ck5, didn't read your whole answer. Deleted my comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match('/\<html\>(.*)\<\/html\>/', $emailbody)
```

If this match, then it is HTML.

Comment: Why the downvote? Most emails does wrap itself inside html-tags if they are HTML.

Comment: I'm with you on this. But to possibly save an unneeded call to `preg_match()` I would propose to first check with `strip_tags()` like Whitehacks suggested. Then, only if the strings differ, use `preg_match` to make sure the body is really HTML.